# Solving boundary-value problems within a specified region

Tags: differential-equations

Is it possible to use DSolve with non-initial boundary conditions?
For example,

```
eqn = a == b x'[z] + c x[z]
```

over the region 0 to L, something like

```
DSolve[{eqn, x[0] == x0, x[L] == xL}, x[z], z]
```

I wonder if maybe my approach is wrong.

This gives the error `For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions lead to an empty solution`. I guess it needs to know more about `L` but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start with only one boundary condition, solve the equation and then impose the second boundary condition.

This then leads to a restriction of the parameters of the ODE, similar to that known as eigenvalue.

Here we go:

```
eqn = a == b x'[z] + c x[z];
```

Repeating first the unsucsessful attempt

```
DSolve[{eqn, x[0] == x0, x[L] == xL}, x[z], z]
```

> During evaluation of In[9]:= DSolve::bvnul: For some branches of the
>   general solution, the given boundary conditions lead to an empty
>   solution. >>

```
(* Out[9]= {} *)
```

During evaluation of In[9]:= DSolve::bvnul: For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions lead to an empty solution. >>

```
Out[9]= {}
```

Now the solution with just one boundary condition is

```
xx[z_] = x[z] /. DSolve[{eqn, x[0] == x0}, x[z], z][[1]]

(* Out[6]= (E^(-((c z)/b)) (-a + a E^((c z)/b) + c x0))/c *)
```

Imposng the second boundary condition and solving e.g. for the parameter "a":

```
sol = Solve[xx[L] == xL, a]

(* Out[12]= {{a -> -((c (x0 - E^((c L)/b) xL))/(-1 + E^((c L)/b)))}} *)
```

The solution is then

```
xxL[z_] = xx[z] /. sol[[1]] // FullSimplify

(* Out[21]= (-x0 + E^((c (L - z))/b) (x0 - xL) + E^((c L)/b) xL)/(-1 + E^((c L)/b)) *)
```

In Latex:

$$\frac{(\text{x0}-\text{xL}) e^{\frac{c (L-z)}{b}}+\text{xL} e^{\frac{c L}{b}}-\text{x0}}{e^{\frac{c L}{b}}-1}$$

Solving for the other two parameters would give

```
Solve[xx[L] == xL, b]

(* Out[10]= {{b -> ConditionalExpression[(c L)/(
    2 I \[Pi] C[1] + Log[(a - c x0)/(a - c xL)]), C[1] \[Element] Integers]}} *)

Solve[xx[L] == xL, c]
```

> During evaluation of In[11]:= Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be
>   solved with the methods available to Solve. >>

```
(* Out[11]= Solve[(E^(-((c L)/b)) (-a + a E^((c L)/b) + c x0))/c == xL, c] *)
```